# Elm: accessing common fields in union

Tags: elm, gadt, union-types

I am trying to model a type as a union where each member of that union has properties in common with all other members.

I am currently achieving this like so:

```
type alias File = {
    name : String
  }

type CommonFileState extra = CommonFileState {
    id : String
  , file : File
  } extra

type alias ValidFileState = CommonFileState {
    validatedAt : Int
  }
type alias InvalidFileState = CommonFileState {
    reason : String
  }
type alias LoadingFileState = CommonFileState {}

type FileState = Valid ValidFileState | Invalid InvalidFileState | Loading LoadingFileState
```

Now if I want to read one of those common properties on any given `FileState`, I must match against each member of the union:

```
getId : FileState -> String
getId fileState = case fileState of
  Valid (CommonFileState {id} extra) -> id
  Invalid (CommonFileState {id} extra) -> id
  Loading (CommonFileState {id} extra) -> id
```

This feels wrong to me, because I have to duplicate the property access for each member. If I needed to manipulate this property somehow (e.g. concatenating something onto the string), I would also have to duplicate this.

I want to be able to easily access common properties of my union, and operate on those common properties.

When I started searching for other ways to do this, I found one alternative was to nest the union inside a record, which also holds the common properties:

```
type alias ValidCurrentFileState = {
    validatedAt : Int
  }
type alias InvalidCurrentFileState = {
    reason : String
  }
type alias LoadingCurrentFileState = {}

type CurrentFileState = Valid ValidCurrentFileState | Invalid InvalidCurrentFileState| Loading LoadingCurrentFileState

type alias File = {
    name : String
  }

type alias FileState = {
    id : String
  , file : File
  , currentState : CurrentFileState
  }

getId : FileState -> String
getId {id} = id
```

However this is awkward because I have to name the nested union, which adds a level of unnecessary indirection: "file state" and "*current* file state" are conceptually the same.

Are there any other ways of doing this which don't have the problems I mentioned?

Comment: Opinion-based questions are off-topic on SO because they're not a good fit for the format. See [help/on-topic]. You should ask this on [the Elm forums](https://discourse.elm-lang.org/) instead.

Comment: That said, I don't see that they are conceptually the same. `CurrentFileState` seems more like a `ValidationState` to me, and not even file-specific from what I can see.

Comment: In this example they might appear the same, but that union isn't just about validation. It's about the current stage a file is in (in the context of a state machine). Perhaps I should improve my example.

Comment: Updated my example to make it clear the union isn't just about validation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are thinking about this the wrong way around.

The purpose of modelling (in Elm) is capture the possible states of your data, and to exclude - in your model - 'impossible' states, so that the compiler can statically prevent the code every creating such states.

Once you're happy with your model, you write the helpers you need to make your core logic easy to express and to maintain.

I suspect I would normally go with your second approach, but I don't know all the issues you need to account for.